# I keep getting UnicodeErrors opening a CSV file although adding utf-8 encoding

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I know the questions sounds generic but here is my problem.
I have a csv file that will always cause UnicodeErrors and errors like csv.empty although I am opening the file with utf-8
like this

```py
    with open(csv_filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
```

A workaround I found is to open the file I want, copy the lines and save to a new file(with visual code studio) everything works fine.

Someone told me that I have to use pandas. Is it true?
Is there a difference between opening a file with CSV and Pandas?

Comment: Depending on the unicode issue, you may or may _not_ have better luck with pandas.

Comment: Have you tried opening the file with a different encoding?

Comment: No, you don't *have* to use pandas unless you want to use pandas. Pandas is not merely an alternative csv-loading module. In any case, it won't help with your encoding issues.

Comment: @G.Anderson I see. Thank you for your time

Comment: @iamchoosinganame yes with the same results

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thank you very much for your explanation

Comment: If you get Unicode errors reading the file with UTF-8, then it isn't encoded in UTF-8.  You have to know the correct encoding.  The `chardet` module can help you guess.  If you are on Windows, then knowing the localized version of Windows you are using can usually narrow down the possibilities to the ANSI or OEM encoding used on that version of Windows.  For example, US Windows uses `cp1252` and `cp437` for Windows- and console-based default non-Unicode encodings, but it will vary by country.

Comment: @MarkTolonen chardet is what warns me about cp1252, but when I try, I get other errors and it's go on and on. _csv.Error: line contains NULL byte is what I get when I try c1252

Comment: Provide a hexadecimal dump of the bytes in the file.  NULL bytes indicate it could be UTF-16, for example.  If possible, give a link to the entire file as long as it isn't sensitive data.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I've already found the answer it's indeed utf-16, thank you very much for your time and tour effort I really appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas will load the contents of the csv file into a dataframe

The csv module has methods like reader and DictReader that will return generators that let you move through the file.

With Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv('file.csv')
df.to_csv('new_file.csv',index=False)
```

Comment: While this is a good basic answer, it doesn't address the question OP is really asking, about whether using pandas will fix a "csv file that will always cause UnicodeErrors"

Comment: In this case @IakovosBelonias I believe the title of your question is misleading, and your real question is buried in the text. You might have better luck being more descriptive. See this link on the [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @G.Anderson Any ideas how I should change the title?